# Cocoa validateUserInterfaceItem and menu item hiding

Tags: cocoa, menu, nsmenu

Using validateUserInterfaceItem it is possible to disable/enable a menu item but I need a similar behaviour to hide menu items, have you some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem

Some details in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/index.html).

**Update:**
NSMenus do not hide NSMenuItems if `validateMenuItem:` returns `NO`. The according NSMenuItem gets disabled (Which tells the user that the functionality is there, but currently not applicable).
This behavior is also suggested in [Apple's HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGMenus/XHIGMenus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000356-TPXREF117). (See the second paragraph in the "Naming Menu Items" section)

Two other notes about NSMenuItem's `enabled` state:

- `setEnabled` only works if `autoenablesItems:` of the hosting NSMenu is set to `YES`
- The default implementation of `validateMenuItem:` seems to traverse the responder chain to check if the target/action of a NSMenuItem is available.

Comment: You are right but I've a context menu and I want to show only valid "contextual" items instead of having dozen of menu items and only a couple enabled

Answer (score 0):

You could use -(BOOL) validateMenuItem: to remove a menu item when it was unneeded and insert it when required.

See the [Menu documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/RemovingMenu.html)

Comment: Calling setHidden inside validateMenuItem doesn't hide the menu, I don't understand why

Comment: Did you try calling setHidden from somewhere else? I use it in one of my projects (also for a context menu) and it works like a charm there. Maybe something trivial (Outlet not connected?)